How to get data through the following SQL Join query
Let's say there's a joining of two tables, Table A and table B. I want to get the rows where the VOYAGE_NAME in Table B is "GRACIOUS ACE 0077A" and PORT_CODE in Table A is "ABC". I also want the data where the Voyage_Name in Table B is "ADRIA ACE 0045A" and PORT_CODE in Table A is "DEF".
This is my query:
SELECT 
    a.port_code,
    a.ata_berth_stamp,
    a.atd_berth_stamp,
    a.ata_end_sea_stamp,
    a.atd_start_sea_stamp,
    b.pic_uid,
    a.updt_stamp
FROM
    pcc_app_own.voy_port_call a,
    pcc_app_own.voy b
WHERE 
    a.voy_uid = b.voy_uid
   AND a.del_flg = 'N'
   AND b.voy_name = 'GRACIOUS ACE 0077A'
   AND a.port_code = 'ABC'

In this query, I cannot apply the two conditions together. Because I do not want to fetch the data with GRACIOUS ACE 0077A voyage and DEF Port Code. I want two rows, each row with the combination of one VOYAGE_NAME and one PORT_CODE against it.
I tried like this:
WHERE 
    a.voy_uid = b.voy_uid
    AND a.del_flg = 'N'
    AND b.voy_name = 'GRACIOUS ACE 0077A'
    AND a.port_code = 'ABC'
    AND b.voy_name = 'ADRIA ACE 0045A'
    AND a.port_code = 'DEF'

With this the problem is that I am being shown the row where b.VOY_NAME = 'GRACIOUS ACE 0077A' and a.PORT_CODE = 'DEF' along with the row where b.VOY_NAME = 'GRACIOUS ACE 0077A' and a.PORT_CODE = 'ABC'

It sounds like you want to run 1 set of logic against both tables and a 2nd  set of logic on same tables?  If so you can do an OR statement.  Though you have to put the AND's in ()  So where (this =that and that = this) OR (this = this and that = that).  Keep an eye on the parens  .  If you want any logic to apply to both sets of data, you can put that first outside the parens.

Please add sample data and desired results.

Start with switching to explicit JOIN syntax. Then use regular AND/OR in the WHERE clause.

This comma-separated join syntax is out-dated by decades. It was used in the 1980s and early 1990s, but since the SQL standard of 1992 introduced explicit joins (FROM pcc_app_own.voy_port_call a INNER JOIN pcc_app_own.voy b ON b.voy_uid = a.voy_uid) we use these instead. Another thing is your table aliases: Table aliases are meant to enhance readability. Names like a and b do the opposite, because we always have to look up which alias is which table. Use mnemonic aliases instead, e.g. v for voy and vpc for voy_port_call.

Take care you don't run in a query with 4, 10 or 20 possible combinations you need to combine with AND, OR, CASE etc. If you note you will need further combinations/conditions, better create a mapping table and join it.

Please proper join.  It's been around for over 30 years!!!

I suggest you add your 2 criteria pairs using OR
WHERE a.voy_uid=b.voy_uid AND a.del_flg='N'
AND
(
  (b.voy_name ='GRACIOUS ACE 0077A' AND a.port_code='ABC')
  OR
  (b.voy_name ='ADRIA ACE 0045A' AND a.port_code='DEF')
)

